# Partitioning SSD for flashcache

Tags: 13.04, ssd, flashcache

I am trying to setup my HDD + SSD on my Win7/Ubuntu dual booting laptop to work with flashcache. Part of my ssd (/dev/sdb1) is already partitioned for ExpressCache on Windows 7. For Ubuntu, I am following the directions [here](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/blob/master/README-DKMS).

However, I do not know which filesystem to use for the cache device and none of the guides specify it. Should I use ext4 like I use on my system or should it be HFS+ as it is how ExpressCache does it for Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

It does not use any filesystem.  Also you might want to look at using bcache instead, since it is now part of the upstream kernel rather than a third party module.